# Connecting .lyr and shapefile query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-layer, layer-file

How do I add or join a .lyr to a shapefile?

I have a shapefile of a city's zoning districts and, separately, the .lyr, which shows the correct colors for each zoning classification.

Based on another thread, I tried going to Properties _ Source and changing the Source to point to the shapefile, but then the color distinctions disappeared.

I am new to GIS.

Comment: Hello, i am assuming you use arcmap because of the .lyr file. if so, you can load and connect your .lyr data in the symbology menu of your shapefile and select a row that features your symbology or labelling

Comment: Please include a link to the other "thread" that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

A LYR file just points to the data but is not data. It handles cartographic representation like symbology labeling and scale dependency